# How to get the innertext of a certain web element using Selenium and VBA? (Troubleshooting Help)

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, xpath, css-selectors

I'm having trouble getting the inner text of a web element on this page (Using VBA + Selenium): https://www.accuweather.com/en/ch/geneva/313082/daily-weather-forecast/313082?day=2

I'm trying to get the text (The "20°") in the following element:

```
<div class="temperature" style="">20°</div>
```

I tried using `mystring = driver.FindElementByCss(".row.first > .temperature:nth-of-type(2)").text` but for some reason it doesn't seem to work, it returns an empty value in Excel, as if it's not getting anything from the element.

I'd appreciate any help, I've been trying to get this working for a little while now.

Comment: Does it need a wait before? I would also use .history .temperature as the css selector

Comment: driver.findElementByClassName("temperature").text Try to see if it's the text getting error cause of the weird symbol or the css selector?

Answer (score 0):

To get the inner text of a web element i.e. **21°** using VBA and [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) you can use either of the [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- *FindElementByXPath*:

  ```
  mystring = driver.FindElementByXPath("//h2[@class='title' and text()='Day']//following-sibling::div[@class='temperature']").text
  ```
- *FindElementByCss*:

  ```
  mystring = driver.FindElementByCss("div.content-module div:nth-of-type(2) div.temperature").text
  ```